# Automatically adjusting ylim with stat_summary

Tags: r, ggplot2

`ggplot2` adjust the `ylim` automatically for the data points. Is there any way to adjust the `ylim` for `stat_summary` too?

```
df <- structure(list(Varieties = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L,
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("F9917", "Hegari", "JS263",
"JS2002"), class = "factor"), Priming = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L,
3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("CaCl2", "Dry",
"Hydropriming", "KNO3", "OnFarmpriming"), class = "factor"),
    PH = c(225.8, 224.26, 228.9, 215.82, 230.3, 227.7, 232.8,
    221.1, 260.2, 230.8, 236.75, 230.5, 250.56, 230.74, 240.64,
    226.7, 268.4, 233.4, 243.33, 232.7, 252.04, 233.1, 237.14,
    220.6, 265.55, 234.93, 240.04, 218.21, 300.55, 245, 243.5,
    234.65, 253.3, 233.5, 238.62, 225.93, 255.74, 233.64, 238.1,
    230.93, 246, 240.33, 246.08, 221.7, 250.54, 242.87, 251,
    225.32, 251.47, 245.4, 266.74, 227.73, 290.62, 246.68, 256.4,
    225.83, 282.67, 240.58, 258.35, 235.87)), .Names = c("Varieties",
"Priming", "PH"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 60L
))

p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Varieties, y=PH, group=Priming, shape=Priming, colour=Priming))+
     stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", size=2, aes(group=Priming, shape=Priming, colour=Priming))+
     theme_bw()
p1 <- p1 + stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(group=Priming, shape=Priming, colour=Priming))
print(p1)
```

[image: See]

See extra space in ylim for stat_summary values. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: In the next version, the ylim will be adjusted based on the range after stats calculation.

Comment: Is this version available on Github?

Comment: @MYaseen208 Yes, [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2). You'll want the current development version, probably. Or you could just wait until March when it will (hopefully, cross your fingers) be released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach, using `plyr` to prep the data before plotting

```
df <- ddply(df, .(Varieties, Priming), transform, meanPH = mean(PH))
ggplot(df, aes(Varieties, meanPH)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = Priming, color = Priming))
```

Answer (score 3):

The current "official" answer for 0.8.9 is, I believe, that you can't, at least not automatically, and not without preprocessing the data as Ramnath indicates. Most people asking this question, or some variant of it, are pointed towards setting the limits manually using `coord_cartesian`.

The reason `stat_summary` behaves this way is that it sort of assumes that you aren't going to *just* plot the summaries, but at least some of the underlying data as well, so it sets up the plotting area using the underlying data frame.

However, I found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/browse_thread/thread/34eac7669b35c0d/b532b693ac6a4c26?lnk=gst&q=stat_summary+ylim#b532b693ac6a4c26) thread on the ggplot2 list that suggests this behavior might change in the upcoming 0.9.0 release. (The thread is a little vague, but I read it as implying that in the next version, if the *only* layer you add is form `stat_summary` then the plot limits will be calculated based on the summaries, not the original data. I could be wrong though.)